# Не работает скрипт переборки

Tags: jquery

есть так скрипт `

```
function activateboxmenu(num) {
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(el) { 
if (el === num) { 

var ('dow' + el) = jQuery('.dow' + el).text();
jQuery('.dw' + el).html('dow' + el);
}

}); 
}
jQuery('.down1').click(function() {activateboxmenu(1)});
jQuery('.down2').click(function() {activateboxmenu(2)});
jQuery('.down3').click(function() {activateboxmenu(3)});
jQuery('.down4').click(function() {activateboxmenu(4)});
jQuery('.down5').click(function() {activateboxmenu(5)});
```

консоль пишет что неопределена переменная, как ее записать в данном случае? 
Спасибо

Comment: а что это за код `var ('dow' + el)` ?

Comment: а что вы вообще делаете? Нельзя вашу задачу решить, используя один общий класс `.down` для всех элементов,  навесить на них какой нить атрибут `data-tag`, из которого  получить этот ваш индекс, и использовать один обработчик, без всяких там бесполезных циклов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function activateboxmenu(num) {
  [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(el) { 
    if (el === num) { 
      var dow = jQuery('.dow' + el).text();
      jQuery('.dw' + el).html(dow);
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: мне больше интересно зачем тут в принципе цикл этот

Comment: @teran Этого мы, возможно, никогда не узнаем - `down`, `dow`, `dw`.